# Angular, include observable data in a mapped array

Tags: angular, observable

I have a service that takes in a type of data and a set of selected items as an array. It needs to respond to the call as an array of objects. My mock data has worked find but now I'm hooking up to an API which is in another service:

```
public getDataSet(type: string, data: Observable<object>) {
  // loop through each item
  const dataSet = data.map(item => {
    // get the start time
    const x = moment(item.hid.timeStarted.epochSecond);

    // get the percent
    const y = type === 'metrics' ? item.percentage : item.messageCount;

    // set the x/y values for the chart
    return {x: x, y: y};
  });

  return dataSet;
}

public getChartData(type: DataTypes, chartData: []) {
  const params = this.getParams();
  const data = chartData.map(item => {
    // create an empty set, the value of them item, and get the chart points
    const set = {};
    const dataValues = type === 'metrics' ?
      this.metricService.getMetricsData(params.app, params.dc, params.node, item)
      : this.countService.getCountsData(params.app, params.dc, params.node, item);

    // store the label and chart points
    set['label'] = item;
    set['data'] = this.getDataSet(type, dataValues);

    return set;
  });

  return data;
}
```

Obviously in `getDataSet` there's an issue with `chartData.map` since `chartData` is an observable. Not sure how to get that data out of the returned api call to manipulate and return it to the component waiting on the data.

Answer (score 0):

Observables are just a reference to an imaginary "pipe" where information flows, you can subscribe to them (observe), so you get notified and consult data once they are emitted by the source that controls that Observable.

If you're passing to a method an Observable, you can't loop over the items, you need to subscribe to it, wait til information is dispatched and only then loop over your received info (if it is an iterable).

In your case you're making a HTTP call, so once you subscribe to `data` inside `getDataSet`, you're ready to go. The problem there is that you can't return from `getDataSet` to `set['data']` since you're handling data async. You'll have to look for a different approach.